# WebMatrix PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix Beta 3 which has support for php 5.2 and 5.3 I am able to run php pages but when I am trying to connect to mySql DB its not working.

Can anyone please suggest me the right way of doing it.

The connection code is written in a file called dbinfo.php which resides under config folder

```
<?php
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'test';

$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Could not select database");

//Below function added to allow customized unescaping.
function mysql_unescape($sRet_VAL=""){
  $sRet_VAL = str_replace('\"','"',$sRet_VAL);
  $sRet_VAL = str_replace("\'","'",$sRet_VAL);
return $sRet_VAL;
}
?>
```

and I am using this file as follows

```
<?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/dbinfo.php');
?>
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * from temp";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: So what's "not working"?

Comment: the page is not showing any result. I have checked the query its working fine in MySql

Comment: You are only running the query. You don't have any code to show the "result".

Comment: I have not shown that code, just to keep the code short and simple

Comment: So, you are getting a "Could not connect" error from the code in dbinfo.php? Or you are getting the error from:
die("Error: " . mysql_error());

Comment: No I am not getting any error. I am simply receiving "undefined" as the output where I should get the result.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code where you are getting undefined, since none of the code you have posted is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

it worked seems like webmatrix do not recognize  I replaced it wilt <>php echo $varData ?> and it worked.